# Need to validate REST API body requests

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have some doubts  related with sequelize . Please help me to resolve those . I want to validate REST API body requests using sequeulize . is that good approach ? if YES , how can i do that ? if NO , do i need to use any 3rd party NPM library for that ? like fast-validators

Example : I want to validate whether user has  empty username & password inputs. is that possible me to use sequeulize to do that ?

Comment: you should use Express validator or any validator library because they provides you more functions(features), so you can sanitize data properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Sequelize.js is an orm for javascript.

There are many validators packages in npm, search for them in npm and sort by popularity to find the fittest for your code structure.